# How to get a test overview in large python / django projects

Tags: python

Assume you have a large python/django project with a fair amount of functions, models and dependencies between models.

There are a lot of tests split across multiple files. How would one gain the overview of what functionality / exception cases has actually been tested?

- Tests are lengthy -> it takes a lot of time to read through the complete unittest file to find the exact one that one is looking for
- dependencies between modules can be in multiple test files -> one does not necessarily know where to look

**Is there a tool / standard procedure how to gain overview over tests, e.g. a tabular form etc. ?**

**Update:** The question is not about coverage,

```
# code
def division(x, y):
    return x/y


# tests
def test_division_integers():
"""Test if we can divide integers""" 
    assert division(6, 3) == 2
```

would have 100% coverage but I don't have a test for division by 0, feeding function with strings, ...
I 'd rather have some overview

```
| Test Name              | Description | Params |
| ---------------------  | ----------- | ------ |
| test division integers | <docstring> |        |
```

Comment: Are you looking for a *code coverage* tool…?

Comment: No, with code coverage I can see which lines of code have been tested, but I cannot gain an overview if a certain functionality has been tested; i updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would have 100% coverage but I don't have a test for division by 0, feeding function with strings, ... I 'd rather have some overview

Basically, *your tests* are that. No tool will be able to seriously tell you that you've tested a function with integers but not with 0 and not with strings. What you basically want is to make your tests more readable. In your above example, `assert division(6, 3) == 2` is the information you want to know, and it's right there; but that will obviously get less and less comprehensible for longer and more complex tests.

A tool like [behave](https://behave.readthedocs.io) might be the right thing there, allowing you to write your tests in *very* readable [Gherkin files](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/), and [test tools like behave](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparison.html) produce reports that highlight which of those tests succeeded and which didn't.